# How can I bound $\left|\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^{bi}}\right|$ where $b\gt 0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $b\gt 0$. I tried
$$S=\left|\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^{bi}}\right|$$
converges if
$$T=\left|\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{\left|k^{bi}\right|}\right|$$
converges. And
$$T=\left|\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1}\right|\le 1.$$
Is this correct?

Comment: No.T doesn't bound S.

Comment: @Zhaohui Du So how can I get it right?

Comment: This is one version of the exponential sum that appears in the Riemann Zeta theory and for which non trivial bounds can be found by exponent pair theory. A square root bound (in $n$ - a bit more complicated technically, but roughly)  is equivalent to the lindelof conjecture so this is highly non trivial

Comment: The part for which $k > 2.1b$ is bounded by $50$ or so by kuzmin-landau and the part where $k$ is comparable to $b$ ($2.1b \ge k \ge .000001b$ say is bounded by a constant times square root by the second derivative test (or the exponent pair (.5,.5)), so the hard part is when $k$ is considerably smaller than $b$

Comment: @Conrad For me, it is surprising that it's highly non-trivial. The need for the bound popped up when determining the convergence of the eta function $\eta (s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s}$ via the Dirichlet's test.

Comment: That converges for $\Re s >0$ and since the sum in the post is trivially bound by $\sqrt b$ (and by a constant if you restrict to the part where $k > > b$) that follows by partial summation). The hard part is at small $n$ vs $b$

Comment: Beating the trivial $n$ bound for $n << \sqrt b$ requires some moderately difficult results either in RZ theory (Riemann Siegel) or in exponent pairs ( the A process), but for convergence where $n \to \infty$ the trivial $b$ bound and partial summation works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me put a quick answer leaving out details that are standard in ANT:

The sum in the post is trivially bound by $\sqrt b$ up to some logarithmic factors, 
(which is precisely what one expects by the RZ bound on the imaginary axis which is O($\sqrt b$) up to negligible logarithmic factors by the functional equation) and this follows from the second derivative test immediately, as for $f(x)= \frac{x}{2}+ \frac{b \log x}{2 \pi}$ for which the original sum is $-\sum_{k=1}^{n} {e^{2\pi i f(k)}}$, the second derivative is ~ $\frac{b}{x^2}$, so the second derivative test gives the sum ~ $\sqrt b$ ( there are details like splitting it in $\log_{2} n$ binary parts on $n$, s.t $M \le k \le 2M$ etc but they are standard). This immediately by partial summation gives the convergence of $\eta (s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s}$ for $\Re s >0$, uniform in any $\Re s > a >0$

A bound of $\sqrt n$ is equivalent to the Lindelof conjecture (technically we need the one below to account for the case $b >> e^n$ say):

$\left|\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^{bi}}\right| \le C_{\epsilon}n^{\frac{1}{2} + \epsilon}(2+b)^{\epsilon}$, for all $n \ge 1, b>0, \epsilon >0$

The hard part is beating the $\min ({n, \sqrt b})$ bound, especially when $n << \sqrt b$ when we need moderately advanced results from RZ theory (Riemann Siegel say) or from exponent pairs theory (A process) say.

But for convergence of $\eta$ as noted, we do not need this stuff since that is concerned with high $n$ compared with $b$ and there indeed there are trivial (in context) bounds

(edit later about exponential sum $S = \sum_{M \le k \le 2M}e^{2\pi i f(k)}$ estimates - there are two basic ones and then they can be refined using various methods; in both cases we assume $f$ smooth enough and $f',f''$ monotonic and with $||x||$ the distance from $x$ to closest integer we have;

Thm 1: Kuzmin-Landau: If $||f'(x)||\ \ge \delta >0, x \in [M,2M]$, then $S=O(\frac{1}{\delta})$ with universal constant (I think 4 works)

(Mordell has a very neat proof of this in a very general sequence setting which is in the proceedings of the ICM 1954 and is also presented in the Iwaniec-Kowalski ANT bible if I remember right)

Thm 2: Second derivative test (due to Van der Corput I think); if now $\lambda \le |f''(x)| \le a\lambda, x \in [M,2M], a, \lambda >0$, then $S=O(aM\sqrt{\lambda}+\frac{1}{\sqrt \lambda})$ with again universal constant (I think 8 works here).

(note also that we need $\lambda << 1$ as otherwise the trivial estimate will do, while the second term is required if $\lambda$ is very small).

This is proved by carefully splitting $[M,2M]$ in intervals ($aM\lambda +2$ in number) where $||f'|| \ge \delta$ for some small parameter $\delta$, and intervals of length at most $\frac{2\delta}{\lambda}$ ($aM\lambda+1$ in number) applying K-l on first kind, trivial estimates on second and making the two estimates equal with $\delta = \sqrt \lambda$

Comment: Are you thinking to EMSF when relating $f''$ with $\sum_{n \le N} e^{2i\pi f(n)}$ or what ?

Comment: Second derivative test - $|f''|$ ~ $\lambda$ on $[M,2M]$ and $f''$ monotonic, then the above sum taken on $[M,2M]$ is $O(M\sqrt \lambda + \frac{1}{\sqrt \lambda})$, here $\lambda=\frac{b}{M^2}$

Comment: This of course only for $M <b$ (up to a constant as otherwise $\delta  < \frac{b} {M}  +.5 < 1-\delta$  for some fixed $\delta$ and kuzmin landau applies and bounds the sum by $O(\frac{1}{\delta)}$

Comment: I don't know what you mean with second derivative test. Do you look at $\sum_{n \in [M,2M]}e^{2i \pi (an^2+bn+c+O(n^{-1}))}$ or at the corresponding integral ?

Comment: If $f'[M,2M]$ doesn't pass through an integer, Kuzmin-Landau applies and gives a bound $O(\frac{1}{\delta})$, where $||f'|| \ge \delta >0$ (where $||.||$ is the distance to closest integer); if now $f''$ is monotonic, and between $\lambda$ and $a\lambda$, where $a$ is a constant (eg 4 here) and $0 < \lambda <.25$ (otherwise the trivial estimate is as good as), then one can split $[M,2M]$ carefully in intervals - some will have $||f'|| >0$ so K-L applies, some will use the trivial estimate and choosing the splitting parameter carefully we get that;

Comment: edited post with details about the 2 fundamental estimates for exponential sums used